# Why is the current scene linked to the Screen view?

Tags: scene

Let's say I have three scenes, A, B and C. In A and B, I use the Default screen layout because I am modelling something and the Compositor for the render. In C, I only use the Compositor where I combine the results of A and B.

I now used the compositor in scene C for a while and switch to A to adjust something. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to switch to the Compositor, I suddenly land in scene C - it was stored with the screen layout.

This is incredibly annoying in larger projects, so: Why does it behave this way and how do I fix it / avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'User Preferences', under 'Interface', check the box next to 'Global Scene' which forces the current scene to be shown in all windows.